# why doesn't this java code work for loneTeen(99, 99)

Tags: java

We'll say that a number is "teen" if it is in the range 13..19 inclusive. Given 2 int values, return true if one or the other is teen, but not both.

```
loneTeen(13, 99) → true
loneTeen(21, 19) → true
loneTeen(13, 13) → false

public boolean loneTeen(int a, int b) {
  if((a>=13  && a<=19)&&(b>=13 && b<=19))
      return false;
  else 
      return true;
}
```

why does it give a true while it is supposed to give false

Comment: Because it's wrong.  If you split out your condition into nested ifs you'll see the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Because your logic is wrong. `&&` doesn't mean XOR (one or the other is true but not both). Use the following:

```
return (a>=13 && a <=19) ^ (b>=13 && b<=19);
```

Answer (score 0):

Java has a **logical XOR** operator `^`

```
return (a>=13 && a<=19) ^ (b>=13 && b<=19);
```